# AWS ECS service not starting tasks anymore

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Until recently ECS is not running my program. I've set up a cluster, container, task and service on ECS, and it has worked fine.

When I trigger the program to run via lambda, ECS starts up like normal, but it does not run the task. I ran the following commands and it looks like the task isn't even running even though ECS is running.

```
curl -s http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata | python -mjson.tool
```

output:

```
{
    "Cluster": "newsapi-dev",
    "ContainerInstanceArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:649469097921:container-instance/newsapi-dev/dbdac61426954f3b9cb8e89c4eabcd3e",
    "Version": "Amazon ECS Agent - v1.51.0 (5c821610)"
}
```

Then I ran

```
curl http://localhost:51678/v1/tasks
```

output:

```
{"Tasks":[]}
```

So it seems that ECS isn't running the task. I'm not sure what has happened because the program ran normally, and I would see the logs in cloud watch.

Furthermore, `Docker ps -a` on the EC2 instances just shows the amazon container running

Below is my task definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "new-api-log",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "MONGODB_PORT",
          "value": "27017"
        },
        {
          "name": "MONGODB_URL",
          "value": "private IP"
        },
        {
          "name": "NEWS_API_CRAWLER_ENV",
          "value": "daily"
        }
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": 1024,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "649469097921.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/newsapi-dev:dev-b2e7988b8a3fa5db5f44775a447c9b8a86ee42ed",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "newsapi-dev"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": null,
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EXTERNAL",
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:649469097921:task-definition/newsapi-dev:55",
  "family": "newsapi-dev",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": null,
  "revision": 55,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the current desired task count on the service? Check in the AWS web console if ECS is attempting to start a task and failing for some reason. Check that the EC2 instance hasn't lost connection to the ECS service (you will see this in the ECS web console as well), and check the last stopped task to see if ECS is reporting an error with the deployment of the task. All these things can be done by just clicking around in the ECS web interface.

Comment: ECS isn't even attempting to start the task; it shows 0.  I'll check to see if EC2 lost connection but the program isn't constantly running. It starts and stop at certain times.

Comment: What "shows 0"? If it shows 0 for "desired task count" then you have configured it such that it will not run anything right now. In that case ECS would be working as intended.

Comment: I've added screenshots to show that the tasks isn't even starting. I have not done anything different, it just stopped running the tasks, and i'm not sure why.

Comment: If I manually start the task, it runs now. But I cannot figure out why it won't start on its own like it used to.

Comment: You're showing screenshots of the **task**, I'm asking what the "desired count" setting is on the **service**.